# Absolute value for sum of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get the absolute value of each element of a list with **n** elements and sum all of them (to get a positive number or zero). I can't use any library because its a school work.

I have tried using the logic below , but one only gets me the absolute value for the sum and the other format is not valid.

`p = [list]`

---

`a=sum(abs(p))`

and also

`p = [list]`

---

`a = abs(sum(p)`

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

> I need to get the absolute value of each element of a list with `n` elements and sum all of them

Your fist approach is a `TypeError` because the absolute value of the whole list is not defined:

```
>>> abs([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'
```

Your second approach calculates the absolute value of the sum, *not* the sum of absolute values.

You should use a loop:

```
result = sum(abs(number) for number in your_list)
```

---

For example:

```
>>> your_list = [1, 2, -3, -5, 6, 0]
>>> # list of absolute values for each number
>>> [abs(number) for number in your_list]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 0]
>>> sum(_)  # sum the list above
17
```

---

If you wanna be fancy, use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map):

```
result = sum(map(abs, your_list))
```

You probably shouldn't turn this in at school because it's a bit advanced, but it never hurts to have a peek into the beauty of functional programming, does it)

Answer (score 1):

Do it manually

```
sum = 0
for i in range(0, len(p)):
    if(p[i] < 0):
       sum = sum - p[i]
    else:
       sum = sum + p[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

use builtin `map`

```py
result = sum(map(abs, list))
```

it applies `abs` to each element and returns new "list" (not actually list)
does not change starting list

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, this might be your solution:

```py
input_numbers = [-1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6] # let's say it's your input

output = sum([abs(number) for number in input_numbers])

print(output) # 21
```

**Explanation**

I think, you are familiar with built-in `sum` and `abs`, so the thing I should explain is 'generator'.

```py
newlist = [abs(number) for number in input_numbers]

print(newlist) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To understand a 'generator', let's just rewrite it in not-one-line style:

```py
newlist = list()
for number in input_numbers:
    newlist.append(abs(number))

print(newlist) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Honestly I don't know what else to add, so feel free to ask some questions :)